# Where to join development teams

Tags: c#, java, c

I hope this question isn't out of focus. I've been wanting to find a way to improve my skills as a programmer. I've tried teaming up with game dev groups at my school and coming up with my own ideas for apps. But these things move very slowly for me and my ideas seem out of my reach due to lack of skill. I don't have a degree yet, but I've been learning to program for around 5-6 years now. I'm very efficient in learning programming skills and using them, but I find that there is a lack of projects for me to join and I have no clue where to find them. Anyone think they can help me out?

My current languages are: C, C++, C#, Java, Python.
I've worked with ASP.NET for web development and also dabbled around SQL Server.

I want to learn more and become more efficient in programming and I think this is a best way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off topic here, so the question is likely to be closed - you may want to try on programmers.se which focuses on these sorts of issues.

Comment: This is definitely Programmers SE territory.

Comment: There are a whole lot of bunch of projects on net. Just browse through and try to optimize them or put a new functionality to them. And the question is really way out of context of StackOverflow.

Comment: @biziclop - No it is not.  Read the FAQ for that site.

Comment: Best advice is to search through F/OSS projects, say on Github or SourceForge, and _find something you like_. It's no fun volunteering on projects you don't enjoy. Maybe find a bug on your favourite item of software and download the code to try fixing?